# Не работает NPM. Сбой выполнения программы npm.cmd

Tags: node.js, npm

Однажды у меня вылетел непонятный еррор, и я решил переустановить ноду. После этого у меня перестал работать npm. Когда я пишу npm то получаю следующий результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавил путь к ноде и нпм в PATH, но проблема все равно не была решена. Далее когда я пытаюсь запустить нпм в папке с нодой вылезает следующее окно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]